# iOS Compatibility on different iOS Operation Systems

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode9

I wanted to ask how compatibility on different iOS operation systems works in iOS. For example If I develop an app on `Xcode 9.2` and `Swift 4` for `iOS 11`, should it work on `iOS 9`?

I am coming from Android background which you specify the minimum Android OS that is needed for the app to run in the Gradle file. Does anything similar exist on iOS?

Comment: General items should work for example (UITableview,alertView,scrollview) but items built for iOS 11 will crash on iOS 9 unless avoided if the os is not 11.

Comment: development target desides that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Very simple solution:

Set deployment target as 9.0 in your build target general settings. iOS will automatically handle support from 9.0 onwards for a build (your app).

Your app/build will be allowed to use/import frameworks and other libraries, compatible to minimum deployment target, only.

[image]

More detail about [App Deployment Target](https://help.apple.com/xcode/mac/current/#/deve69552ee5) from Apple.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it will work on iOS9
With Xcode 9.2 and swift4 you can develop an application for ios8.0 and above.

In your project setting, you have to select your development target

[image: Select Project -> Select your target -> In general Tab - Select your deployment target]

Answer (score 1):

Please set your deployment target to 9.0

[image: Deployement Target]

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is backward compatibility, but for older iOSes you have to check version when using newer API. Luckily we've got availability attributes (@available)

If you want to know HOW it works, basically for Swift your application has its own swift standard library embedded into binary of your application. In case of Objective C – newer iOSes keep sdk's of older versions to maintain backward compatibility.